# How to show complete description in Toast content in uwp

Tags: uwp, toast

I am trying to show an alert toast but some characters are getting cut. I need to either show a complete description message or if I can add Ellipsis character at the end.

Answer (score 1):

> I need to either show a complete description message

It's by-default, toast text has length limit. if the length too long to display, it will be cut. For the scenario, we suggest calculate content length before set to xml. if text is too long please replace extra character with ellipsis. During the testing, the maximum length of content is 139.

```
var str = "Content";
var sub = str.Remove(139 - 3, 3);
var newstr = sub + "...";
```

Comment: How do I calculate the maximum length of content?

Comment: You have not calculate the content length, you just need to remove after 136 index string and append with ellipsis.